# Pythonic way to limit ranges on a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, clipping

Is there a better way to do this?

```
if a > 1:
    a = 1
if a < 0:
    a = 0
```

I was thinking of using a function because I have a lot of these in my code,
Was curious if there was a shorter comprehensible way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you describe is usually called *clipping*. There are several ways to do clipping.

## Library (`numpy`)

You can use [`numpy.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) for that:

> ```
> numpy.clip(a, a_min, a_max, out=None)
> ```

So:

```
import numpy

numpy.clip(x,0,1)
```

Although since function calls in Python are expensive, and `numpy` usually processes data in batch, for a single value it will result in computational overhead.

For example:

```
>>> x = -2.5
>>> numpy.clip(x,0,1)
0.0
>>> x = 2.5
>>> numpy.clip(x,0,1)
1.0
>>> x = 0.5
>>> numpy.clip(x,0,1)
0.5
```

Usually you use `numpy` to perform **operations on (large) matrices**, for instance if you have to process a 1000x1000 matrix, than using `numpy` will definitely pay off.

## Pure Python

A **pure python approach** can be obtained with:

```
max(0,min(1,x))
```

But here you have **two calls**, as a result, it will be slower than using `if` statements.

Finally if you stick with the `if`-code, you can optimize it a tiny bit by using an `elif`:

```
if x < 0:
    x = 0
elif x > 1:
    x = 1
```

Or a more generic function:

```
def clip(x,min,max):
    if x < min:
        return min
    elif x > max:
        return max
    return x
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html Check this out, or ```a = 1 if a > 1 else 0```would at least reduce it to one line

Answer (score 4):

I'd always use something like `max(0, min(1, x))`.
If x is more than 1, `min(1, x)` will be 1, and `max(0, 1)` is still 1.
If x is less than 0, `min(1, x)` will be `x`, and `max(0, x)` will be 0.